# Salesforce devolopment using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide, training

I would like to learn Salesforce development by using Eclipse. I am requesting for you to suggest online material for me to go through?

Comment: Have you tried using the power of Google? There are plenty of resources out there covering using Salesforce with Eclipse. http://bit.ly/1Cp4voB

Comment: Hi Alex,Thank ..

Comment: HI Alex, Thankyou. I Installed Eclipse and Force.com plug in then imported my testing project. upto this is fine. Now I would like to do edit or append objects, write classes, workflows, triggers and validation rules by using eclipse. i searched in google but i failed. can i get any notes which is available in online like  " Working on salesforce using eclipse".... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is just another IDE for Coding/Deployment for Salesforce. For installation, please go through the following link [Eclipse Salesforce IDE Installation guide](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/install-force-com-ide-in-eclipse-salesforce-com/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use MavensMate for development on Force.com platform

Comment: Can you expand upon this in any way? Why do you suggest this?

Comment: It is user friendly, more powerful and lightweight. You can read more info here - http://mavensmate.com/